# Capturing the result of explain() in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In pyspark, running:

`sdf = sqlContext.sql("""SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c1 """)`

and then:

`sdf.explain(extended=True)`

it prints the logical and physical plans of the query execution.

My question is: **How can I capture the output in a variable, instead of printing it?**

`v = sdf.explain(extended=True)` naturally, does not work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of [`explain`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.explain) (version 2.4 or older), you see that :

```py
def explain(self, extended=False):
    if extended:
        print(self._jdf.queryExecution().toString())
    else:
        print(self._jdf.queryExecution().simpleString())
```

Therefore, if you want to retrieve the explain plan directly, just use the method `_jdf.queryExecution()` on your dataframe :

```py
v = sdf._jdf.queryExecution().toString()  # or .simpleString()
```

---

From [3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.explain), the code is :

```py
print(
    self._sc._jvm.PythonSQLUtils.explainString(self._jdf.queryExecution(), explain_mode)
)
```

Removing the print, you get the `explain` as a string.

Comment: Thank you! I've leaned quite a lot from this example. Now searching  how to overcome the truncation of the string of the execution plan (but that is another topic :) ).

Comment: @MattMoehr updated the post with the version reference.

Comment: From that link to the source in "3.0", the values for `explain_mode` are "simple" and "extended".