# find hive table partitions used for a hive query from pyspark sql

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive external table with few columns partitioned by date. Data is in avro format. I wanted to prove or see which partitions are being used for my query from spark sql.

I know we can find partitions information from hive cli using "EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY SELECT * from table where date ='2019-12-20'. I also know to get the execution plan from spark sql using explain() method.but this doesn't show me partitions information.

Please help me with a way to see table partitions used information from spark.

Thanks

Chaithanya M

Comment: From my experience- pyspark always reads through all partitions. I was hoping you can restrict it somehow, but neither ```.filter()``` nor ```.where()``` nor any form of filtering from ```spark.sql()``` helped. I think the only way to restrict partitions is to read directly directories, linked to partitions you want to read.

Comment: Show pls what .explain reveals. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski :Thank you Skibinski for your response. But i have concern here, do we have to loop through every directory and read the file . for example if i had to read 2019 related files , i will have 365 directories created one per day.do we have to really do this , we dont have a better way of handling this ?