# Save a result of printSchema() function to variable in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ddl

I'm using the `printSchema` function to infer schema of Json file. I want to save the result of this function call in a variable to parse it line by line so that I can  extract a structure of a schema and convert it in a DDL schema for creating a table in hive.

How can this be done?

Comment: `schema = df.schema` ?

Comment: There's also `df.dtypes`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing the result of explain() in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you inspect the [source code for `printSchema()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.printSchema), you will see that this function just does the following:

```
print(self._jdf.schema().treeString())
```

Therefore, you can save the output as follows:

```
printSchemaString = df._jdf.schema().treeString()
```

Other references:

- [Saving result of DataFrame show() to string in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55653609/saving-result-of-dataframe-show-to-string-in-pyspark)
- [Capturing the result of explain() in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark)