# How to get referenced columns of a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a [PySpark DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) is it possible to obtain a list of source columns that are being referenced by the DataFrame?

Perhaps a more concrete example might help explain what I'm after. Say I have a DataFrame defined as:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
source_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("pru", 23, "finance"), ("paul", 26, "HR"), ("noel", 20, "HR")],
    ["name", "age", "department"],
)
source_df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, age, department FROM people")
df = sqlDF.groupBy("department").agg(func.max("age").alias("max_age"))
df.show()
```

which returns:

```
+----------+--------+                                                           
|department|max_age |
+----------+--------+
|   finance|      23|
|        HR|      26|
+----------+--------+
```

The columns that are referenced by `df` are `[department, age]`. Is it possible to get that list of referenced columns programatically?

Thanks to [Capturing the result of explain() in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124386/capturing-the-result-of-explain-in-pyspark) I know I can extract the plan as a string:

```py
df._sc._jvm.PythonSQLUtils.explainString(df._jdf.queryExecution(), "formatted")
```

which returns:

```
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (6)
+- HashAggregate (5)
   +- Exchange (4)
      +- HashAggregate (3)
         +- Project (2)
            +- Scan ExistingRDD (1)


(1) Scan ExistingRDD
Output [3]: [name#0, age#1L, department#2]
Arguments: [name#0, age#1L, department#2], MapPartitionsRDD[4] at applySchemaToPythonRDD at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, ExistingRDD, UnknownPartitioning(0)

(2) Project
Output [2]: [age#1L, department#2]
Input [3]: [name#0, age#1L, department#2]

(3) HashAggregate
Input [2]: [age#1L, department#2]
Keys [1]: [department#2]
Functions [1]: [partial_max(age#1L)]
Aggregate Attributes [1]: [max#22L]
Results [2]: [department#2, max#23L]

(4) Exchange
Input [2]: [department#2, max#23L]
Arguments: hashpartitioning(department#2, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=60]

(5) HashAggregate
Input [2]: [department#2, max#23L]
Keys [1]: [department#2]
Functions [1]: [max(age#1L)]
Aggregate Attributes [1]: [max(age#1L)#12L]
Results [2]: [department#2, max(age#1L)#12L AS max_age#13L]

(6) AdaptiveSparkPlan
Output [2]: [department#2, max_age#13L]
Arguments: isFinalPlan=false
```

which is useful, however its not what I need. I need a list of the referenced columns. Is this possible?

Perhaps another way of asking the question is... is there a way to obtain the explain plan as an object that I can iterate over/explore?

---

UPDATE. Thanks to the reply from @matt-andruff I have gotten this:

```py
df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan().treeString().split("+-")[-2]
```

which returns:

```py
' Project [age#1L, department#2]\n            '
```

from which I guess I could parse the information I'm after but this is a far from elegant way to do it, and is particularly error prone.

What I'm really after is a failsafe, reliable, API-supported way to get this information. I'm starting to think it isn't possible.

Comment: maybe just `df.columns`

Comment: This will give me the columns in the final dataframe, which isn't what I'm after.

Answer (score 4):

There is an object for that unfortunately its a java object, and not translated to pyspark.

You can still access it with Spark constucts:

```
>>> df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan().apply(0).output().apply(0).toString()
u'department#1621'
>>> df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan().apply(0).output().apply(1).toString()
u'max_age#1632L'
```

You could loop through both the above `apply` to get the information you are looking for with something like:

```
plan = df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan()
steps = [ plan.apply(i) for i in range(1,100) if not isinstance(plan.apply(i), type(None)) ]
iterator = steps[0].inputSet().iterator()
>>> iterator.next().toString()
u'department#1621'
>>> iterator.next().toString()
u'max#1642L'

steps = [ plan.apply(i) for i in range(1,100) if not isinstance(plan.apply(i), type(None)) ]

projections = [ (steps[0].p(i).toJSON().encode('ascii','ignore')) for i in range(1,100) if not( isinstance(steps[0].p(i), type(None) )) and steps[0].p(i).nodeName().encode('ascii','ignore') == 'Project' ]
dd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(projections)
df2 = spark.read.json(rdd)
>>> df2.show(1,False)
+-----+------------------------------------------+----+------------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|child|class                                     |name|num-children|output|outputOrdering|outputPartitioning|projectList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |rdd |
+-----+------------------------------------------+----+------------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|0    |org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec|null|1           |null  |null          |null              |[[[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference, long, [1620, 4ad48da6-03cf-45d4-9b35-76ac246fadac, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId], age, true, 0, [people]]], [[org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference, string, [1621, 4ad48da6-03cf-45d4-9b35-76ac246fadac, org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ExprId], department, true, 0, [people]]]]|null|
+-----+------------------------------------------+----+------------+------+--------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
df2.select(func.explode(func.col('projectList'))).select( func.col('col')[0]["name"] ) .show(100,False)
+-----------+
|col[0].name|
+-----------+
|age        |
|department |
+-----------+
```

`range` --> Bit of a hack but apparently `size` doesn't work.I'm sure with more time I could refine the range hack.

You can then use json to pull the information programmatically.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful but its still not giving me the answer I require. Your code returned `department` and `max_age`. That's not what I want, I want `department` and `age`. Hopefully I can explore that `_jdf` object to find what I'm after.

Comment: Your reply enabled me to get a bit closer, but in a very inelegant way. I've updated my post above accordingly.

Comment: If you want to access it programatically you would need to write a javaclass and then call the Java class in pyspark.  This would allow you to intergate the system correctly until they update the pyspark code to allow access to the plan.

Comment: I wasn't satisfied with your string answer so I dove in deeper and now you can access it programically.

Comment: Matt this looks great, thank you so much. However I think I'm missing something, I've executed my code above to derive `df` then executed `plan = df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan()` followed by `[ plan.apply(i).toString() for i in range(1,100) if not isinstance(plan.apply(i), type(None))]` but that only returns an empty string. I'm sure there's user error somewhere, I'll keep looking.

Comment: I fixed the typo in my code.  It should have been `[ plan.apply(i) for i in range(1,100) if not isinstance(plan.apply(i), type(None))]`

Comment: Still can't get it to work I'm afraid Matt. I pasted my code at https://pastebin.com/E5Yyv7Fp . I get error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250174/discussion-between-matt-andruff-and-jamiet).

Answer (score 0):

I have something that, while not being an answer to my original question (see Matt Andruff's answer for that), could still be useful here. Its a way to get all the source columns referenced by a `pyspark.sql.column.Column`.

Simple repro:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, SparkSession
SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
col = f.concat(f.col("A"), f.col("B"))
type(col)
col._jc.expr().references().toList().toString()
```

returns:

> <class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
> "List('A, 'B)"

its definitely not perfect, it still requires you to parse out the column names from the string that is returned, but at least the information I'm after is available. There might be some more methods on the object returned from `references()` that makes it easier to parse the returned string but if there is, I haven't found it!

Here is a function I wrote to do the parsing

```py
def parse_references(references: str):
    return sorted(
        "".join(
            references.replace("'", "")
            .replace("List(", "")
            .replace(")", "")
            .replace(")", "")
            .split()
        ).split(",")
    )

assert parse_references("List('A, 'B)") == ["A", "B"]
```

Comment: And here is a commit where I am using it: https://github.com/jamiekt/jstark/commit/dd0991c1241cf6934ff4b5c9028465442f1670d0

Answer (score 0):

PySpark is not really designed for such lower-level tricks (which begs more for Scala that Spark is developed in and as such offers all there is inside).

This step where you access [QueryExecution](https://books.japila.pl/spark-sql-internals/QueryExecution/) is the main entry point to the machinery of Spark SQL's query execution engine.

The issue is that py4j (that is used as a bridge between JVM and Python environments) makes it of no use on PySpark's side.

You can use the following if you need to access the final query plan (just before it's converted into RDDs):

```
df._jdf.queryExecution().executedPlan().prettyJson()
```

Review the `QueryExecution` API.

### QueryExecutionListener

You should really consider Scala to intercept whatever you want about your queries and [QueryExecutionListener](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/util/QueryExecutionListener.html) seems a fairly viable starting point.

There is more but it's all over Scala :)

> What I'm really after is a failsafe, reliable, API-supported way to get this information. I'm starting to think it isn't possible.

I'm not surprised since you're throwing away the best possible answer: Scala. I'd recommend using it for a PoC and see what you can get and only then (if you have to) look out for a Python solution (which I think is doable yet highly error-prone).

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I’d come to a similar conclusion. I did post an answer on here which i euphemistically described as “not perfect”, for similar reasons to those that you have articulated. In my case I am writing a pyspark-based library hence my preference for a python-based solution, if one exists.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below codes, this will give you a column list and its data type in the data frame.

```python
for field in df.schema.fields:
    print(field.name +" , "+str(field.dataType))
```

Comment: This will give me the fields in the final dataframe, which isn't what I'm after.